# How to show results on desired sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is not showing the results on the "All Stock Analysis" sheet.

I tried doing a test after the activation of each worksheet (Range("I1).Interior.Color = vbGreen) and cell I1 turns green on each of the desired worksheets. What other tests can I try? No error msg pops up.

```vb
Sub AllStocksAnalysisRefactored()
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime  As Single

    yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?")

    startTime = Timer
    
    'Format the output sheet on All Stocks Analysis worksheet
    Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
    
    Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" + yearValue + ")"
    
    'Create a header row
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Ticker"
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"

    'Initialize array of all tickers
    Dim tickers(12) As String
    
    tickers(0) = "AY"
    tickers(1) = "CSIQ"
    tickers(2) = "DQ"
    tickers(3) = "ENPH"
    tickers(4) = "FSLR"
    tickers(5) = "HASI"
    tickers(6) = "JKS"
    tickers(7) = "RUN"
    tickers(8) = "SEDG"
    tickers(9) = "SPWR"
    tickers(10) = "TERP"
    tickers(11) = "VSLR"
    
    'Activate data worksheet
    Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
    
    'Get the number of rows to loop over
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '1a) Create a ticker Index
    Dim tickerIndex As Single
    tickerIndex = 0

    '1b) Create three output arrays
    Dim tickerVolumes(12) As LongLong
    Dim tickerstartingPrices(12) As Single
    Dim tickerendingPrices(12) As Single
    
    ''2a) Create a for loop to initialize the tickerVolumes to zero.
    For i = 0 To 11
    
        tickerVolumes(i) = 0
         
    ''2b) Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
        For j = 2 To RowCount
    
        '3a) Increase volume for current ticker
            tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) + Cells(j, 8).Value
        
        '3b) Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
            If Cells(j - 1, 1).Value <> tickers(tickerIndex) And _
              Cells(j, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex) Then
                
                tickerstartingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value
            
        'End If
            End If
                  
        '3c) check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker
         'If the next row’s ticker doesn’t match, increase the tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
            If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> tickers(tickerIndex) And _
              Cells(j, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex) Then
                
                tickerendingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value

            '3d Increase the tickerIndex.
                tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1
            
        'End If
            End If
            
        Next j
    Next i
    
    '4) Loop through your arrays to output the Ticker, Total Daily Volume, and Return.
    For i = 0 To 11
   
        Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
   
    Next i
    
        'Formatting
    Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
    Range("A3:C3").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    Range("A3:C3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("B4:B15").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Range("C4:C15").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Columns("B").AutoFit

    dataRowStart = 4
    dataRowEnd = 15

    For i = dataRowStart To dataRowEnd
        
        If Cells(i, 3) > 0 Then
            
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            
        Else
        
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
            
        End If
        
    Next i

    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & (endTime - startTime) & _
      " seconds for the year " & (yearValue)

End Sub
```

Here is how "All Stock Analysis" sheet will look after running the code:
[image: All Stock Analysis outlook]

Comment: You are activating the worksheet 12 times instead of doing it once and then writing the result 12 times (once for each `Whatever`).

Comment: It seems to me that you are setting the color of the result cells but not their values. Therefore your result cells are blank.

Comment: Consider this approach:- You need to have 3 values for each of 12 tickers, a total of 36 data. Why not create an array, like `Dim Arr As Variant: Redim Arr(1 To 12, 1 To 3)`, fill all the data into this array, paste the completed array to the result area and end the macro with formatting the cells in the output sheet? It's difficult to help you more without knowing the data in the annual sheets but consider deploying worksheet functions like SUMIFS() instead of loops. Why should you need 150 lines of code to fill 36 cells? Consider `Dim Tickers() As String: Tickers = Split("AY,CSIQ,DQ", ",")`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to scan the data sheet once if you use a [dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) to convert the ticker ID to an array index number.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AllStocksAnalysisRefactored()

    Const SHT_NAME = "All Stock Analysis"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsYr As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, yr As String, iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim t As Single: t = Timer
   
    ' choose data worksheet
    yr = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on ? ", "Enter Year", Year(Date))
 
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsYr = wb.Sheets(yr)
    On Error GoTo 0
     ' check if exists
    If wsYr Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & yr & "' does not exists.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Initialize array of all tickers
    Dim tickerID, tickerData(), i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim dict As Object, sId As String
    tickerID = Array("AY", "CSIQ", "DQ", "ENPH", "FSLR", "HASI", _
                    "JKS", "RUN", "SEDG", "SPWR", "TERP", "VSLR")
    
    n = UBound(tickerID) + 1
    ReDim tickerData(1 To n, 1 To 5)

    ' create dict id to index
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To n
        sId = UCase(Trim(tickerID(i - 1)))
        tickerData(i, 1) = sId ' id
        tickerData(i, 2) = 0 ' volume
        tickerData(i, 3) = 0 ' start price
        tickerData(i, 4) = 0 ' finish price
        tickerData(i, 5) = 0 ' count
        dict.Add sId, i
    Next

    'Get the number of rows to loop over
    iLastRow = wsYr.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
    ' Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
    ' A=ticker, F=Price , H=Volume
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
        sId = UCase(Trim(wsYr.Cells(iRow, "A")))
        If dict.exists(sId) Then
            i = dict(sId)
            ' volume
            tickerData(i, 2) = tickerData(i, 2) + wsYr.Cells(iRow, "H") ' volume
            ' start price when count is 0
            If tickerData(i, 5) = 0 Then
                tickerData(i, 3) = wsYr.Cells(iRow, "F")
            End If
            ' end price
            tickerData(i, 4) = wsYr.Cells(iRow, "F")
            ' count
            tickerData(i, 5) = tickerData(i, 5) + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    'Format the output sheet on All Stocks Analysis worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHT_NAME)
    ws.Cells.Clear
    With ws
        .Range("A1").Value2 = "All Stocks (" & yr & ")"
        With .Range("A3:E3")
            .Value2 = Array("Ticker", "Total Daily Volume", "Start Price", "End Price", "Return")
            .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
       .Range("A4").Resize(n, 4).Value2 = tickerData
       .Range("B4:D4").Resize(n).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
       .Range("E4").Resize(n).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
       .Columns("B").AutoFit
    End With
 
    ' coloring
    For Each cell In ws.Range("E4").Resize(n)
       cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]-RC[-2])/RC[-2]" ' end-start/start
       If cell > 0 Then
          cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
       Else
          cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
       End If
    Next
   
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "This code ran for (" & yr & ")", vbInformation, Int(Timer - t) & " seconds"

End Sub
```